# How to take LocalFile in the AppPackage Installation

Tags: c#, file, uwp

I want to distribute some configuration file in my UWP application.

So I would like to get them, and put them directly in the local folder during the installation.

I know that we can put in in the application folder, but I want to modify them with the code and they are in read-only access. And to delete one because of some private information that I would put in the local Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading the included file with [Storage­File.Get­File­From­Application­Uri­Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync), that area will always be read-only.

What you can do is to copy the file to the isolated storage and there change it in whatever way you want to and then use it.

Files bundled with the app cannot be modified or even deleted, they can only be read.

Comment: Thanks for help, but after some research about this, I have see that once the UWP is installed on a device, we can't change the local file by hand (By the file explorer) because they are pretty well hide. Is that true ?

Comment: That is correct. All UWP apps are installed in a hidden folder owned by a system account. Though you can (as an administrator) change the securities and get access to the folder, that is not recommended or even supported!